# Is there anyway to control how MaxImage plugin crops the images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a responsive micro-site with some webpages, each page contains a background image of a male/female model. I am using maximage plugin to render these backgrounds. The problem is: the model is not always in the middle of the background so it is been cropped on the mobile screen. I am trying to control how maximage crops the images!!. Is there anyway to do it?!!! Like cropping the image from the right side only.
is there any other solution?!

your help is very much appreciated!
Thanks